# Android compare ConstantState does not work on 4.4 KitKat

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-4.4-kitkat

I developed an app and everything works great on my s7 and other devices, but I tested it on an older one running 4.4 kitkat and when the app compares the buttons' colours, in 4.4, it doesn't work.

This is the piece of code I'm using:

```
for (Button btn : selectorArrayList) {

        final Button button = btn;

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                /*

                    Check if button color is white or red
                    if white, turn red and activate the
                    selector (category) and if it's red
                    turn white and deactivate the selector
                    category)

                 */

                // I've set the background in the XML Layout as R.color.white

                Drawable pd = (Drawable) button.getBackground();

                if (pd.getConstantState().equals(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.color.white).getConstantState())) {

                ...
```

At this very point on a newer version of the OS it decides the states are equal, and on 4.4 (haven't tried on other versions) they're not.

Does anyone know if I'm doing something wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: try to use ColorDrawable to get white color

Comment: it does work comparing it like this: if ((pd.getColor()&0xffffff) == 0xffffff), do you know the reason why it doesn't work the other way?

Comment: You pass color res in ContextCompat.getDrawable method, maybe old versions can't handle it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, should work:

```
  if (pd.getConstantState().equals(new ColorDrawable(R.color.white).getConstantState()))
```